# How to enable directoryPerDB after mongo restore?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have done the restoring of a huge db using mongo restore.
But in the config directoryPerDb is not provided. 
So the is the any ways I can move the files in each directory?
I dont want to do the restore again as the size is huge.